# Which graphics driver should I install in Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

Output of `lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'`

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carrizo [1002:9874] (rev ca)
06:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265] [1002:6900] (rev 83)
```

Output of `uname -r`

```
3.13.0-119-generic
```

Output of `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

If possible, please give detailed steps too.

Answer (score 0):

Can You Try Below like this

Please Find a Application

[image]

**After Select That application**

[image]

After Select Tab Drivers --> there u can find required Drivers

[image]

Comment: Try like this it maybe useful

Comment: It is unable to detect the AMD card. Says, `Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]: Unknown`. But, is displaying the 3 options. I'll try with fglrx-updates

Answer (score 0):

It looks like originally you installed Ubuntu 14.04 because the kernel version is 3.13.

If you did not install graphical HWE stacks, then the graphical stack should be the original from 14.04.

In this case you can install `fglrx-updates` and they will work.

If you install a system from a 14.04.5 iso image, it has the 4.4 kernel and a new graphical stack. `fglrx` will install, but won't work.

Comment: I had installed 14.04.2 from the ISO image and accidentally updated to 14.04.5. Do I need to upgrade the kernel too to get fglrx-updates to work?

Comment: It is not "accidentally". It is OK since the kernel is 3.13. `fglrx` should work, but I am not sure if it supports Radeon R7 M260/M265

Comment: fglrx not working. I have asked a separate question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926385/problem-with-ubuntu-graphics-card-drivers)